# Perl: replace binary content

Tags: regex, perl, binaryfiles

I need to replace a binary content with some other content (textual or binary) in Perl.

If the content is textual I can use s/// to replace content.

```
 my $txt = "tomturbo";
 $txt =~ s/t/T/g;      # TomTurbo
```

But that is not working if the content is binary.

Is there an easy way to handle that??

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a *binary content*?

Comment: If you mean that you read from a "binary" file (under `:raw`), then you'll need to `unpack` what you read before regex can work with it.  (I don't know whether you consider that "easy" or not :)

Comment: The above comment **stands corrected** by ikegami answer. I'm leaving it for now since that may well be what you want to do, for convenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl's regex engine will work with arbitrary strings.

```
s/t/T/g
```

is no different than

```
s/\x{74}/\x{54}/g
```

meaning it will change the value of characters from 74<sub>16</sub> to 54<sub>16</sub>. The regex engine doesn't care whether value 74<sub>16</sub> means `t` or something else.

In binary data, character A<sub>16</sub> doesn't indicate the end of a line, so you'll want to use the `s` flag, avoid the `m` flag, and avoid using `$`.

Furthermore, you'll find the `i` flag and the built-in character class (e.g. `\d`, `\p{Letter}`, etc) useless unless you are matching against strings of decoded text (strings of Unicode Code Points), but you may otherwise use any feature of the regex engine.

Comment: That works only for single characters I think. I need it for whole strings that are in a scalar (e.g. s/$binval/$newval/)

Comment: No. Perl's regex engine will work with arbitrary strings. But that doesn't excuse the need to form a proper regex (`s/\Q$binval\E/$newval/`).

Comment: WOW! That is a real easy way!