# perl replace non UTF-8 characters or binary contents with whitespace

Tags: perl

I have a file with non-ascii characters.

```
$ org od -t c -t x1 -A d tmp.txt
0000000   S   o   -   c   a   l   l   e   d    217    204   l   a   b
         53  6f  2d  63  61  6c  6c  65  64  f4  8f  b1  84  6c  61  62
0000016   e   l   e   d    217    204   p   a   t   t   e   r   n   s
         65  6c  65  64  f4  8f  b1  84  70  61  74  74  65  72  6e  73
0000032    217    204   c   a   n       b   e    217    204   u   s
         f4  8f  b1  84  63  61  6e  20  62  65  f4  8f  b1  84  75  73
0000048   e   d    217    204   w   i   t   h    217    204   s   i
         65  64  f4  8f  b1  84  77  69  74  68  f4  8f  b1  84  73  69
0000064   n   g   l   e   ,        217    204   d   o   u   b   l   e
         6e  67  6c  65  2c  20  f4  8f  b1  84  64  6f  75  62  6c  65
0000080   ,        217    204   a   n   d    217    204   t   r   i
         2c  20  f4  8f  b1  84  61  6e  64  f4  8f  b1  84  74  72  69
0000096   p   l   e    217    204   b   l   a   n   k   s   .
         70  6c  65  f4  8f  b1  84  62  6c  61  6e  6b  73  2e
```

As you can see, `\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}` has several occurrences. I want to replace `\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}` with whitespace. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307921/perl-replace-binary-content), I try:

```perl
s/\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}/ /g;
tr/\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}/ /;
```

It doesn't work.
But if I remove this two lines in the script:

```perl
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );
```

It works. Why?

I suspect that it is because perl only deals with characters, but `\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}` is not regarded as a character. Is there a way to remove `\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}` or any other binary contents or non UTF-8 characters with perl?

Comment: They do work. The former replaces the four-char sequence with a single space. The latter replaces all occurrences of any of those four chars with a space. Either the string doesn't contain what you think it does, or you are mistaken about it not working.

Comment: Re "*non UTF-8 characters*", It is valid UTF-8 for U+10FC44. (This is a private use code point.)

Comment: @ikegami I think It's not valid utf-8. And if without `use utf8;use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );`, it works.

Comment: @ikegami execute`bytearray([0xf4,0x8f,0xb1,0x84]).decode('utf-8')` in python, the result is `'\U0010fc44'`, it cannot be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the file may contain `"\x{f4}\x{8f}\x{b1}\x{84}"`, your string contains `"\x{10FC44}"` — `"\N{U+10FC44}"` if you prefer — because you decoded what you read. As such, you'd need

```perl
tr/\N{U+10FC44}/ /
```

---

It's a private-use Code Point. To replace all 137,468 private-use Code Points, you can use

```perl
s/\p{General_Category=Private_Use}/ /g
```

`General_Category` can be abbreviated to `Gc`.
`Private_Use` can be abbreviated to `Co`.
`General_Category=` can be omitted.
So these are equivalent:

```perl
s/\p{Gc=Private_Use}/ /g
```

```perl
s/\p{Private_Use}/ /g
```

```perl
s/\p{Co}/ /g
```

`Co` makes me think of "control", so maybe it's best to avoid that one. (Controls characters are identified by the `Control` aka `Cc` general category.)